# e2e browser opens and close immedietly

Tags: firebase, protractor, ionic2

I am trying to test my app and followed this link http://lathonez.github.io/2016/ionic-2-e2e-testing/ i merged my app with firebase. Everything worked good, but when i run npm run e2e browser opens and close immediately in my terminal pops an error.

I followed this link http://lathonez.github.io/2016/ionic-2-e2e-testing/

[image]

Actually my issue is that i could not able to see any action takes place in my e2e browser could some on help me

protractorconfig.js

```
 exports.config = {
        baseUrl: 'http://192.168.1.2:8100/',

        specs: [
           '../app/pages/home/home.e2e.ts',
           '../app/pages/Admin/admin.e2e.ts',
           //'../app/pages/Listing/lisitngPage.e2e.ts'

        ],

        exclude: [],

        framework: 'jasmine2',

        allScriptsTimeout: 110000,

        jasmineNodeOpts: {
            showTiming: true,
            showColors: true,
            isVerbose: false,
            includeStackTrace: false,
            defaultTimeoutInterval: 400000
        },

        directConnect: true,

        chromeOnly: true,

        capabilities: {
            'browserName': 'chrome',

            'chromeOptions': {
                'args': ['--disable-web-security']
              }
        },

        onPrepare: function() {
            var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');

            jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter({displayStacktrace: true}));

            browser.ignoreSynchronization = false;
        },
        useAllAngular2AppRoots: true
    };
```

gulpfile.ts

```
import { join } from 'path';

const config: any = {
  gulp: require('gulp'),
  appDir: 'app',
  testDir: 'test',
  testDest: 'www/build/test',
  typingsDir: 'typings',
};

const imports: any = {
  gulp: require('gulp'),
  runSequence: require('run-sequence'),
  ionicGulpfile: require(join(process.cwd(), 'gulpfile.js')),
};

const gulp: any = imports.gulp;
const runSequence: any = imports.runSequence;

// just a hook into ionic's build
gulp.task('build-app', (done: Function) => {
  runSequence(
    'build',
    (<any>done)
  );
});

// compile E2E typescript into individual files, project directoy structure is replicated under www/build/test
gulp.task('build-e2e', ['clean-test'], () => {
  let typescript: any = require('gulp-typescript');
  let tsProject: any = typescript.createProject('tsconfig.json');
  let src: Array<any> = [
    join(config.typingsDir, '/index.d.ts'),
    join(config.appDir, '**/*e2e.ts'),
  ];
  let result: any = gulp.src(src)
    .pipe(typescript(tsProject));

  return result.js
    .pipe(gulp.dest(config.testDest));
});

// delete everything used in our test cycle here
gulp.task('clean-test', () => {

  let del: any = require('del');

  // You can use multiple globbing patterns as you would with `gulp.src`
  return del([config.testDest]).then((paths: Array<any>) => {
    console.log('Deleted', paths && paths.join(', ') || '-');
  });
});

// run jasmine unit tests using karma with PhantomJS2 in single run mode
gulp.task('karma', (done: Function) => {

  let karma: any = require('karma');
  let karmaOpts: {} = {
    configFile: join(process.cwd(), config.testDir, 'karma.config.js'),
    singleRun: true,
  };

  new karma.Server(karmaOpts, done).start();
});

// run jasmine unit tests using karma with Chrome, Karma will be left open in Chrome for debug
gulp.task('karma-debug', (done: Function) => {

  let karma: any = require('karma');
  let karmaOpts: {} = {
    configFile: join(process.cwd(), config.testDir, 'karma.config.js'),
    singleRun: false,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    reporters: ['mocha'],
  };

  new karma.Server(karmaOpts, done).start();
});

// run tslint against all typescript
gulp.task('lint', () => {

  let tslint: any = require('gulp-tslint');

  return gulp.src(join(config.appDir, '**/*.ts'))
    .pipe(tslint())
    .pipe(tslint.report('verbose'));
});

// build unit tests, run unit tests, remap and report coverage
gulp.task('unit-test', (done: Function) => {
  runSequence(
    ['lint', 'html'],
    'karma',
    (<any>done)
  );
});
```

Comment: A few debug steps could be deleting your node_modules and then reinstalling them, trying to run your protractor.conf.js file without gulp. If you can run your protractor.conf.js file without gulp that means gulp is attempting to look for your chromedriver in the wrong location. I can't give you exact help without more information (gulpfile) and because you are using typescript which could be obfuscating the normal stacktrace.

Comment: @sonhu check it once i updated it